# Java: run jar with dependencies

Tags: java, spring, maven

I've packaged my mvn project.

After that, my `jar` files only contains my hand coded classes:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
me/
me/jeusdi/
me/jeusdi/slab/
me/jeusdi/slab/MyService.class
me/jeusdi/slab/App.class
me/jeusdi/slab/MyConfig.class
me/jeusdi/slab/MyServiceImpl.class
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/me.jeusdi.slab/
META-INF/maven/me.jeusdi.slab/slab/
META-INF/maven/me.jeusdi.slab/slab/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/me.jeusdi.slab/slab/pom.properties
```

Nevertheless, I need declared maven dependencies:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>me.jeusdi.slab</groupId>
  <artifactId>slab</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>slab</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <kafka.streams.version>3.4.0</kafka.streams.version>
    <spring.version>6.0.5</spring.version>

    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        <version>${kafka.streams.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Why `spring-core` dependency is not present into my jar.

I need to run my jar. Currently, I'm using:

```
java -cp target/slab-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar App
```

Any ideas about how to embed or locate my dependencies and run my application?

Comment: Did you consider to use spring boot? It provides a maven plugin, that can create executable jars which contain all the needed dependencies: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html
It even can start a web server if needed. 
And here is the documentation of the spring-boot-maven-plugin: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins.html#build-tool-plugins.maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Maven to create an uber-jar that contains all the classes.
You can as well ask Maven to download the dependencies for your.

What I usually do is to generate the jar the same as you do, but then automatically download all the dependencies into a lib folder.
To make running the jar as easy as `java -jar ...` I have Maven even add the classpath into the manifest.
The only drawback is that you now need to distribute the jar and it's libs in exactly this directory structure.
The advantage is that any signed jar will preserve it's signature and thus validity.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dist</outputDirectory>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>${mainclass}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dist/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: What about [shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)?

Comment: The shade plugin would create the uber-jar I mentioned above. But as I do not use it I don't have an example. Feel free to post it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include the jar with dependencies you could add the following

```
<plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Just replace fully.qualified.MainClass in
`<mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>`
with which ever class has main

To Build it you can run
`mvn clean compile assembly:single`

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/574650/5622596  for more details.

As to how to run a jar one possible way is to run the following
`java -jar NameOfJar.jar`
Just replace `NameOfJar.jar` with whichever jar you created